# Google Sheets Script to insert new row and copy some values if cells do not match

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to JavaScript and am trying to create a script that will insert a new row and insert certain values if two cells do not match.

At this point I have no idea where next to turn. The idea is that for each work order a line for the project manager is added at the end. My issue, I believe is with the location of the row insertion and the evaluation of the two values. Rows end up inserted either above the data or in between every line. Thanks for the help.

```
function karpify() {
  onOpen();
  sort();
  checkInsert();
}

/** Build a menu item
From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#menus_for_add-ons_in_google_docs_or_sheets 
**/

function onOpen(e) { 
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Transform'); 
  if (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
    // Add a normal menu item (works in all authorization modes).
    menu.addItem('Insert PM Rows', 'karpify');
  } else {
    // Add a menu item based on properties (doesn't work in AuthMode.NONE).
    var properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    var workflowStarted = properties.getProperty('workflowStarted');
    if (workflowStarted) {
      menu.addItem('Insert PM Rows', 'karpify');
    } else {
      menu.addItem('Insert PM Rows', 'karpify');
    }
    menu.addToUi();
  }
}

function sort() {

  // Global vars
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var employeeIndex = values[0].indexOf("Employee");
  var employeeCol = (employeeIndex++);
  var woCol = (values[0].indexOf("Work Order")+1);

  /**  Variables for customization:

  Each column to sort takes two variables: 
  1) the column index (i.e. column A has a column index of 1
  2) Sort Asecnding -- default is to sort ascending. Set to false to sort descending **/

  //Variable for column to sort first  
  var sortFirst = woCol; //index of column to be sorted by; 1 = column A, 2 = column B, etc.
  var sortFirstAsc = true; //Set to false to sort descending

  //Variables for column to sort second
  var sortSecond = employeeCol;
  var sortSecondAsc = true;

  //Number of header rows  
  var headerRows = 1; 

  /** End Variables for customization**/

  /** Begin sorting function **/
  var range = sheet.getRange(headerRows+1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows()-headerRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.sort([{column: sortFirst, ascending: sortFirstAsc}, {column: sortSecond, ascending: sortSecondAsc}]);
}

function checkInsert() {

  // vars for check 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var employeeIndex = values[0].indexOf("Employee");
  var employeeCol = (employeeIndex + 1);
  var woIndex = values[0].indexOf("Work Order");
  var woCol = woIndex+1;
  var jcIndex = values[0].indexOf("Job Code");
  var jcCol = parseInt(jcIndex+1);
  var hoursCol = (values[0].indexOf("Regular Hours")+1);
  var rateCol = (values[0].indexOf("Regular Rate")+1);
  var columns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var rows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  //vars for insert
  for (var row = 2; row <= rows; row++) {
    var insert = sheet.insertRowAfter(row);
    var test = values[row][woCol];
    var test2 = values[row++][woCol];
    var range = sheet.getRange(row,1,1); // store the range to copy 
    if (test !== test2) {
      sheet.insertRowAfter(row);
      var newRange = sheet.getRange(row+1, sheet.getMaxColumns(), 1); // store the location of the new row
      range.copyTo(newRange); // copy saved row data to the new row
      sheet.getRange(row+1,rateCol).setValue(27);
      sheet.getRange(row+1,employeeCol).setValue("Smith, Bill");
      sheet.getRange(row+1,hoursCol).setValue(.5);
      var rows = sheet.getLastRow();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When redefine a variable, you will overwrite its previous value. So `sort()` in your code doesn't do anything. Please fix it first.

Comment: The sort actually works fine, the issue is with the checkInsert @FisNaN